# Mocking multiple modules in single jest test

Tags: module, mocking, jestjs

I am facing an issue in jest mocking. I can mock 1 module per test file but I am unable to mock multiple modules for single jest test.

E.x.

```
import mock1 from '../mockClass1';
import mock2 from '../mockClass2';

jest.mock('../mockClass1');
jest.mock('../mockClass2');
mock1.mockImplementation(() => {});
mock2.mockImplementation(() => {});
```

But this gives error as 1 of the mocks is not working. Is there a way of mocking both modules as I need them both in **snapshot test** of my class.

Comment: What error are you seeing?  This should work fine..

Comment: I have the same problem. The error is: `TypeError: this.mock2.theTestedMethod is not a function` How did you solve this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, if I try a second mock in the same file the first mock which was working now doesn't.  Did you fix this?

Answer (score -2):

Use another mock-method. I suggest to mock the methods:

```
const mock1: any = {
  methodToMock: jest.fn(() => {})
};
```